# ssh to icloud from linux

Tags: linux, icloud

I am using Linux (kernel 4.11, fedora26). I access `icloud` from web interface. But, I am having some problem with this set up. It is working great with fedora 25.

Is it possible to `scp` my photos to `icloud`. I have googled, and everyone (e.g. [this](https://www.cnet.com/news/how-to-connect-via-ssh-using-iclouds-back-to-my-mac-service/)) is talking about `My Mac Service`.

Comment: While the best case scenario would be to mount your iCloud like a disk, Apple doesn't provide any Linux clients for iCloud so you are kind of SOL there.

Comment: You need an iOS or OSX client to talk to iCloud really, but could build [in theory] something that relies on both. You could I imagine scp to a specific area, which triggered your OS X client copied into your iCloud.